# Copy and paste by columns from one file to another excluding the common first column

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have 2 data files `f1.dat` and `f2.dat`.

`f1.dat`

> 0  a0  b0
>    1  a1  b1
>    2  a2  b2

`f2.dat`

> 0  c0  d0  e0
>    1  c1  d1   e1
>    2  c2  d2   e2

I wish to copy all columns of `f2` except the fist column to `f1`.
`f1` after merging will look like

`f1.dat`

> 0  a0  b0   c0  d0  e0
>    1  a1  b1   c1  d1   e1
>    2  a2  b2   c2  d2   e2

How would I instruct vim to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following sequence of keystrokes:

- in f2.dat file:

  ```
  gg0w<C-v>G$y
  ```
- in f1.dat file

  ```
  gg0$<C-v>G$A<Space><Esc>$p
  ```

Explanations:

- first sequence:

  - <kbd>gg0</kbd> - move to the beginig of the file
  - <kbd>w</kbd> - jump to second word
  - <kbd>C-v</kbd> - start blockwise visual selection
  - <kbd>G</kbd> - jump to last line of file
  - <kbd>$</kbd> - jump to end of that line
  - <kbd>y</kbd> - copy selection
- second sequence:

  - <kbd>gg0</kbd> - move to the beginig of the file
  - <kbd>$</kbd> - jump to end of line
  - <kbd>C-v</kbd> - start blockwise visual selection
  - <kbd>G</kbd> - jump to last line of file
  - <kbd>$</kbd> - jump to end of that line
  - <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> - append one space at the end of line. After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> this will be repeated on all lines of visual block.
  - <kbd>$</kbd> - jump to end of line
  - <kbd>p</kbd> - paste content

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. @Rich Thank you for the edit :) ...